# JSF2 + jetty-maven+plugin + jetty9 annotation issues

Tags: eclipse, maven, annotations, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to setup a maven project in order to be deployed for testing on jetty (not embedded) using eclipse Luna and jetty-maven-plugin but even if annotations should be enabled by default, jsf2 annotations seems to be not scanned.
Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mindthecheck</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenProva</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MavenProva Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
            <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>javascript</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MavenProva</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my managedBean

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ManBean {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        logger.info(name);  
    }

    public void action(){       
        logger.info("my action");
    }
}
```

When I trigger the controller action (by clicking on a jsf button with ajax behaviour) I got:

```
set 27, 2014 10:45:21 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
AVVERTENZA: #{manBean.action}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @20,66 action="#{manBean.action}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'manBean' resolved to null
javax.faces.FacesException: #{manBean.action}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @20,66 action="#{manBean.action}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'manBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @20,66 action="#{manBean.action}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'manBean' resolved to null
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @20,66 action="#{manBean.action}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'manBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 31 more
```

I think the jsf annotation gets not scanned but why does it happen  and is there a solution for that?
Using mvn jetty:run-war, the generated war deployed on a jetty instance is working fine.